# I want to call a create figures with embedded subplots in a loop then call figures later in code and update subplots. How can I do that?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I tried the following but doesn't work. This ends up with figure "R=7" being updated instead of figure "R=5". In other words, I need my subplots to be updatable with new data outside the for loop.

```
unique_inductance=[1,2,3]
unique_resistance=[5,6,7]
for idx,z in enumerate(unique_inductance): 
    fig = plt.figure('R='+ str(unique_resistance[idx]),figsize=(10,10))
    ax=fig.subplots(math.ceil(len(unique_inductance)),math.ceil(len(unique_resistance)),sharex = 'col', sharey = 'row')
    ax[idx,0].set_ylabel(('Resistance Value='+str(unique_resistance[idx])), multialignment='center')
    
    for idxx,zz in enumerate(unique_resistance): 
      ax[idx,idxx].plot(unique_inductance,unique_resistance)
      ax[idx,idxx].set_title('Inductancc Value' + str(unique_inductance[idxx]))    
fig=plt.figure("R=5")
#ax=fig.get_axes()
fig=plt.gcf()
print(fig)

ax[1,1].plot(unique_inductance,unique_resistance)
```

Comment: You get the figure corresponding to R=5, however your ax variable is still from the last loop iteration, (R=7). Hence, you should call `ax = fig.get_axes()` after `fig = plt.figure("R=5")`

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting the error
 `  ax[1,1].plot(unique_inductance,unique_resistance)'
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`
here is a printout of the ax variable after `ax = fig.get_axes() `


`[<AxesSubplot:title={'center':'Inductancc Value1'}, ylabel='Resistance Value=5'>, <AxesSubplot:title={'center':'Inductancc Value2'}>, <AxesSubplot:title={'center':'Inductancc Value3'}>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>]`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix I could find is using reshape()

```
unique_inductance=[1,2,3]
unique_resistance=[5,6,7]
for idx,z in enumerate(unique_inductance): 
    fig = plt.figure('R='+ str(unique_resistance[idx]),figsize=(10,10))
    ax=fig.subplots(math.ceil(len(unique_inductance)),math.ceil(len(unique_resistance)),sharex = 'col', sharey = 'row')
    ax[idx,0].set_ylabel(('Resistance Value='+str(unique_resistance[idx])), multialignment='center')
    
    for idxx,zz in enumerate(unique_resistance): 
        #print(idx)
        #idx=idx+1
      ax[idx,idxx].plot(unique_inductance,unique_resistance)
      ax[idx,idxx].set_title('Inductancc Value' + str(unique_inductance[idxx])) 
    #print(ax.    
fig=plt.figure("R=5")
#ax=fig.get_axes()
#fig=plt.gcf()
ax = fig.get_axes()
ax=np.array(ax).reshape(math.ceil(len(unique_inductance)),math.ceil(len(unique_resistance)))
ax[1,1].plot(unique_inductance,unique_resistance)
```